# Zugehörigkeit ausdrücken ohne »von«

Tags: grammar, genitive

Meine Frau und ich besitzen gemeinsam (zu gleichen Teilen) eine Wohnung. Ich kann also, während ich Gäste durch die Wohnung führe, folgende Sätze sagen:

> 1. Das ist die Wohnung **von** meiner Frau.
> 2. Das ist die Wohnung **von** mir.
> 3. Das ist die Wohnung **von** meiner Frau und mir.

Ich kann aber auch Folgendes sagen (vor allem klingt es besser; es ist stilistisch hochwertiger):

> 1. Das ist die Wohnung meiner Frau.
> 2. Das ist meine Wohnung.

Zum Satz 1 gibt es noch eine Alternative, die zwar grammatisch korrekt, aber veraltet und heutzutage ungebräuchlich ist:

> 1. Das ist meiner Frau Wohnung.

Gibt es auch eine grammatisch korrekte Möglichkeit, den Sachverhalt aus Satz 3 ohne das Wort »von« auszudrücken?

Prinzipiell ist es ja leicht möglich, einen Satz zu konstruieren, in dem mehrere Personen dieselbe Sache besitzen:

> Das ist Annas und Heinrichs Auto.

Das, was die Sache schwierig macht, ist das Auftreten der ersten Person (»ich« bzw. »meine« oder »mir«) gemeinsam mit der grammatischen dritten Person (»meine[r] Frau«) in der zu bildenden Nominalphrase.

Das Einzige, was mir als Lösung einfällt, ist dieser Satz:

```
Das ist meine und meiner Frau Wohnung.
```

Allerdings ist mir nicht klar, ob das a) korrekt und b) verständlich ist.

Eine Umschreibung wie »*Das ist die Wohnung, in der ich und meine Frau wohnen.*« lasse ich als Antwort nicht gelten, weil man eine Wohnung besitzen kann, ohne darin zu wohnen. Die beiden Sätze drücken also nicht genau dasselbe aus.

Comment: wie wäre es mit 'unsere' oder 'unsere gemeinsame'?

Comment: Ist dein Problem mit "unsere", dass dieses Wort ansich nicht besagt, wer alles "unsere" ist?

Comment: @Em1 in dem Fall habe ich auch schon "unser beider" gehört, ich weiß nicht, wie korrekt das ist..

Comment: "Eine Umschreibung wie »Das ist die Wohnung in der ich und meine Frau wohnen.« lasse ich als Antwort nicht gelten, weil man eine Wohnung besitzen kann ohne darin zu wohnen." -> Dann halt: "Das ist die Wohnung, die meiner Frau und mir gehört. // die meine Frau und ich besitzen" ;)

Comment: @christian.s "unser beider" reduziert es zwar auf zwei Personen, aber es ist immer noch nicht klar, wer der zweite Teil ist. Vielleicht hast du auch eine Wohnung zusammen mit deinem besten Freund?

Comment: lässt du ein einfaches "Nein" als Antwort gelten? ;) Du sagst selbst, die Sache ist schwierig, vielleicht ist es aber auch gar nicht möglich

Comment: Wenn es dir wichtig ist mit der Aussage eindeutige Besitz- oder Eigentumsverhältnisse zu beschreiben, ist "Das ist meine Wohnung" auch zu ungenau. Sowohl der Mieter als auch der Vermieter einer Wohnung könnte sie zurecht als "meine Wohnung" beschreiben.

Comment: "Meine une meiner Frau Wohnung" ist das korrekte Konstrukt klingt aber leider archaisch. In Satz 1 könnte es auch heißen "Das ist meiner Frau Wohnung" und man hat das gleiche Problem. Etwas umständlicher wäre "Meine Wohnung und die meiner Frau", das wäre zumindest im Kontext auch verständlich, könnte losgelöst aber auch als zwei Wohnungen verstanden werden.

Answer (score 3):

> Diese Wohnung gehört meiner Frau und mir.

Zu einfach?

Answer (score 2):

Man kann den Namen benutzen:

> Das ist Giselas und meine [gemeinsame] Wohnung.

Die Information, dass Gisela auch die Ehefrau ist, kann (und will?) man hier wohl schlecht unterbringen. Informell könnte man sowas wie

> Das ist Frauchens und meine Wohnung.

konstruieren (also einen "Titel" erfinden, der des Possessivpronomens nicht mehr bedarf), aber das ist sicherlich nicht jedermanns Sache.

Wenn aus dem Kontext klar ist, um wen es geht (wenn die Gattin also z.B. daneben steht), tut es auch

> Das ist unsere [gemeinsame] Wohnung.

Comment: +1 für "bedürfen" mit Genitivobjekt!

Comment: geht nicht 'Das ist meiner Frau Giselas und meine Wohnung' ?

Comment: @christian.s: Hm, *geht* möglicherweise; *schön* ist es nicht (doppeltes "mein", doppelter "Besitz"indikator).

Answer (score 1):

`Das ist meine und meiner Frau Wohnung` ist, so wie Deine Alternative, zwar grammatisch korrekt, aber veraltet und heutzutage ungebräuchlich. In der Praxis wird man das also, worauf auch schon die anderen Antworten hinweisen, umschreiben müssen:

> Das ist unsere Wohnung. Das ist die Wohnung von mir und meiner Frau.

Was gefällt Dir an der "von"-Variante eigentlich nicht, oder ist es eine theoretische Frage?

Comment: Wenn nur eine Person als Besitzer genannt wird, ist die Version ohne »von« schöner. Daher habe nach einer von-losen Möglichkeit gesucht. Und zusätzlich interessiert mich auch die Theorie dazu.